# How to debug silent crashes? Multiprocessing python

Tags: python, debugging, crash, multiprocessing, daemon

I have a program that spawns a bunch of worker daemons using the multiprocessing library.

Sometimes these daemons will sporadically fall over and die. This isn't caused by a python-level Exception. The crashes seem to be totally silent...

Can anyone provide tips on how I may go about debugging this issue?

Comment: `multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()`

Answer (score 2):

The [faulthandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html) library might help debug such behavior. Run this code in every process `run` method to save tracebacks into separate files:

```
f = open('fault_%s.log' % multiprocessing.current_process().name, 'w')
faulthandler.enable(file=f, all_threads=True)
```